# "Linking Error: Duplicate public_main in module" while building

Tags: c, linker

I have created a a simple file under one work area, build it and executed successfully. And again created another file under same work area. I am getting linking error like:

`"====Linking===== Error: Duplicate public_main in module...."` while building and I am getting the same error when I try to execute first file also.

Please see the below code and suggest.

File1: n_numbers.c

```
#define N 10

main()  
{

int count;
float sum, number;

count=0;
sum=0;

printf("Enter 10 numbers to calculate the Sum");

while(N<10)
{
scanf("%f", &number);

sum=sum+number;

count=count+1;
}

printf("sum=5.2%", sum);
}
```

File2: two.numbers.c

```
main()
{

int a,b,c;

printf("Enter Two numbers for a and b\n");
scanf("%d %d",&a, &b);

c=a+b;

printf("c=%d", c);

}
```

Comment: "Please show me the solution." - No. **You** please show us the code and the compiler invocation.

Comment: How many functions named `public_main()` do you have in total?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. 'Work area' sounds like a term associated with an IDE; which IDE are you using on which platform? (C compilers per se don't have 'Work areas'; they don't need them.) Also, there is no standard meaning associated with the name `public_main()` in C; only the function `main()` and those listed in the standard C library have special standing. There must be a reason why you write `public_main()` functions, but it is outside the standard. You need to specify what files you are using in your program, and which ones contain `public_main()`.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your problem is:

```
gcc file_a.c
a.out
```

Works

```
gcc file_b.c
a.out
```

Works

```
gcc file_a.c file_b.c

linker error
```

Will be because gcc is trying to make a single executable and each executable must have **exactly** one `main` function.

If file_a and file_b *both* define a function called `public_main` the problem becomes which one is intended in any given invocation - C solves this by a simple rule - *you can only have **one** of each function in each executable*.

N.B. Other languages have different rules, C++ can have multiple functions with the same name but different prototypes, (overloading), or within different classes, (namespaces), *it actually does both via what is called name mangling*.  Python uses namespaces and sophisticated scoping rules, etc.

### Copied from comments!

> Hi Steve, I had only one main() in each executable, but still i am
>   getting same error – user2714972
>
> You have 2 .c files and you are linking them into a single executable,
>   (.exe), that is what gcc does when you give it more than one .c file
>   if you would like to make 2 executables you need to call gcc twice,
>   once with each .c and with -o differcent_exe_name to stop both being
>   called a.out or a.exe – Steve Barnes

If, as some have suggested, you are using an IDE you need to either create separate projects or specify separate targets depending on the IDE.

Comment: It is about `public_main()`, not `main()`. Nevertheless, the answer is applicable, thus +1.

Comment: Hi Steve and Jonathan,

Comment: can anybody please help me out

Comment: Yep! Make sure you have exactly ___one___ definition of `public_main` in all the files linked together!

Comment: Looking at your changes above I see you were doing *exactly* what I said at the start **you can only have one and must have one** `main` **in each executable**.

Comment: Hi Steve, I had only one main() in each executable, but still i am getting same error

Comment: You have 2 .c files and you are linking them into a single executable, (.exe), that is what gcc does when you give it more than one .c file if you would like to make 2 executables you need to call gcc ***twice***, once with each .c and with  `-o differcent_exe_name` to stop both being called a.out or a.exe